# overflow stack size in kotlin class getter on android Service class

Tags: android, kotlin

Kotling language has getter method `get() = value` but I cannot call getter in kotlin class

In extended Android Service Class, I tried to get the getter method like below

```
class IPCService : Service() {

    var number : Int = 0
        get() = number
...
```

but cannot get number variable. just echo error like this

```
2019-09-01 21:59:26.895 9437-9465/com.example.ipc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.ipc, PID: 9437
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1042KB
        at com.example.ipc.IPCService.getNumber(IPCService.kt:13)
        at com.example.ipc.IPCService.getNumber(IPCService.kt:13)
        at com.example.ipc.IPCService.getNumber(IPCService.kt:13)
```

```
class IPCService : Service() {

    var number : Int = 0
        get() = number

    var thread : ThreadClass? = null

    var binder : IBinder = LocalBinder()

...

    // 액티비티와 서비스의 중간 매개체가 클래스
    inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService() : IPCService {
            return this@IPCService // 안드로이드 OS가 생성한 객체의 주소값을 반환 (안드로이드OS의 Binder 클래스)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var ipcService : IPCService? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var intent = Intent(this, IPCService::class.java)

        if (isServiceRunning("com.example.ipc.IPCService") == false) {
            startService(intent)
        }

        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE) // BIND_AUTO_CREATE는 서비스가 실행되지 않을 경우 자동으로 실행

        button.setOnClickListener { view ->
            var value = ipcService?.number
            textView2.text = "value : ${value}"
        }
    }
```

`ipcService?.number` is error.

how can I get the number variable in kotlin?

```
2019-09-01 21:59:26.895 9437-9465/com.example.ipc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: com.example.ipc, PID: 9437
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1042KB
        at com.example.ipc.IPCService.getNumber(IPCService.kt:13)
        at com.example.ipc.IPCService.getNumber(IPCService.kt:13)
        at com.example.ipc.IPCService.getNumber(IPCService.kt:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `number` property calls themselves on `get`. You have to write

```
var number : Int = 0
    get() = field
```

But in Kotlin you can add getter later without any api changes. So you can just write

```
var number : Int = 0
```